# Using void* functions in c++

Tags: c++

Im currently learning c++ and I have a little question here:

I have this method:

```
void *list_t::operator[](list_inx_t n)
{
    if (/*condition*/)
    {
        /*Some code here*/;
        return NULL;
    }

    void *p;
    /*Some code here*/

    return p; 
}
```

And this is code from the main function:

```
list_t A(/*Constructor variables*/);

cout << *(int*)A[0] << endl;

*((int*)A[0]) = 12;

cout << *(int*)A[0] << endl;
```

Is there any "cleaner" way to do this? Something similar to this:

```
cout << A[0] << endl;
A[0] = 12;
cout << A[0] << endl;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain better? Put more code please :)

Comment: Return `int&` instead of `void*`? Or do you have a particular reason for throwing away type safety?

Comment: return references. If you need some genericity make `list_t` a template class

Comment: @MikeSeymour He's apparently returning a pointer because it may be null.  Of course, it should still be an `int*`.  And he should definitely check for the null pointer _before_ dereferencing it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: So throw an exception. Or return `int*` and put up with using `*` and checking the result; that's at least cleaner than requiring freaky casts.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Certainly.  I'm not arguing for the cast.  It's not clear what the actual context is: his client code seems to assume that the returned pointer can't be null, but the code clearly does return a null pointer some of the time.  If he returns a pointer (eg for some error conditions), he must check it before deferencing; if he returns a reference, he needs some alternative way (like exceptions) of handling whatever causes him currently to return a null pointer.

Comment: The real questions are "What do you want to happen when [ ] is invoked on an index that hasn't been previously set?"  "Is your operator returning NULL only because an allocation failed or do you really want NULL at an index to be a valid value (maybe indicating `unknown` or `not yet set`)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to create a list that can store "anything" then you need to learn about templates.  Something along the line of:

```
template<typename Type>
class list_t {
public:
    Type *list_t::operator[](list_inx_t n)
    {
      ...etc
```

or

```
template<typename Type>
class list_t {
public:
    Type & list_t::operator[](list_inx_t n)
    {
      ...etc
```

Will give you the type safety you want.

Comment: You type faster than me :P

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the operator like

```
int & operator[](list_inx_t n);
```

and

```
int operator[](list_inx_t n) const;
```

And call it like

```
cout << A[0] << endl;

A[0] = 12;
```

Comment: The small bit of code he shows us clearly returns a null pointer some of the time, so returning a reference isn't an option.  (Nor is, of course, dereferencing before he checks for a null pointer.  His client code is broken.)

Comment: @James Kanze I suggest not to return null pointer.:) I think there is no yet a client code.:)

Comment: @vlad You always suggest an either irrelevant or blatantly naive solution. So what ...

Comment: His code has a condition where he does return a null pointer---maybe some sort of error handling.  So either he returns a pointer (and the client code checks it before dereferencing), or he adopts some other error reporting method.  (The "correct" solution depends on when he returns the null pointer.  Although I don't really like `[]` which return a pointer---I'd argue for a named function if returning a null pointer is appropriate.)

Comment: @James Kanze The operator has nothing common with pointers. Either it will have undefined behaviour if an element with given index does not exists (preferable solution) or it can through an exception.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The operator does what it's author wants it to do.  In most cases, I'd argue for an assertion failure if the index is invalid, but the judging from the little bit of code which was in the question, the author here wants it to return a null pointer.

Comment: @James Kanze The author wants to return the int value stored  in a node but due to his low qualification tries to return a pointer to void. You may argue but I am sorry it is not interesting.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It must be nice to be able to read people's minds like that, to know what they want, even when they seem to be saying something different. The fact remains that it is perfectly legal for an `operator[]` to return a pointer.

Comment: @James Kanze  We are speaking not about correct syntaxical constructions in C++ but about a design of a class. If the list would be a list of pointers to void I would agree with you. But it is a list of integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_t A;
int * AA = (int *)A;
cout << AA[0] << endl; // or better printf( "%d\n", AA[0] );
AA[0] = 12;
```

Comment: how is printf better than std::cout?

Comment: Because it's easier to do it wrong with printf.   std::cout is *so* restrictive.

Comment: @UmNyobe Because we're trying to make the code as fragile as possible, by using all sorts of type conversions.

Comment: @UmNyobe `std:cout` is for students and beginners. `printf` is compact, powerful and readable.